# Rails deleting records is leaving null columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I delete record like this:

```
ScheduledTask.destroy(params[:scheduled_id])
```

Instead of erasing the record, it sets all its values to null. How to delete the record completely?

Comment: Can you try `delete` instead? `destroy` will trigger callbacks, maybe your callbacks prevent the object from being totally removed.

Comment: The same, all values ale nullify except from id...

Comment: Can you try to output error messages of why your object is preventing from being destroy. e.g: `puts ScheduledTask.destroy(params[:scheduled_id]).errors.full_messages`

Comment: Can you post the source for ScheduledTask? Or at least any callbacks. Are you sure `scheduled_id` is an id of a ScheduledTask object? Do you have a `Scheduled` model? Finally, are you trying to debug this within a database transaction?

Comment: Try it with `destroy!` as it will raise an exception instead of failing silently, so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

ScheduledTask is the name of your entire class rather than a record. At the moment you're telling the entire class to delete the supplied params.

You need to find the record you want to delete, and then call delete on that:

```
 task = ScheduledTask.find(params[:scheduled_id]
 task.destroy
```

Comment: I thought that .destroy(id) works :/ Here is doc: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy Btw I tried your way of dealing with this and the result is the same.

Comment: You're absolutely right - my bad disregard my comment. have you tried using delete instead of destroy?

Comment: I figured it out! The problem was path verb POST. It prevented deleting, instead it updated all values to null. Changing verb to DELETE solved the problem.